# Skip to next in array for batch based off of IF condition

Tags: arrays, batch-file, if-statement

There is probably a simple bit of code but I cannot seem to find anything specific to what I need.

I have an array in a batch file & I am looking to use an IF statement as the condition to let the code continue or have it jump to the next in the array. The IF condition pretty much just checks to see if the C: drive is present. Is it possible w/o adding too may lines?

The ** ** is sudo code

```
SET Array[01]=Server1
SET Array[02]=Server2
SET Array[03]=Server3

FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('SET Array[') do (
IF NOT exist \\%%s\c$ (
    ECHO Server %%s is not reachable & **JUMP TO NEXT IN ARRAY**
) else (
    **xcopy [source] [destination]** )
```

Comment: no need for jumping, if you close your `for` correctly with a `)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FOR /F` command you are using should iterate through all three servers.  You don't need a jump (goto) at all.

This works just fine with my servers.

```
@echo off
SET Array[01]=server1
SET Array[02]=server2
SET Array[03]=server3

FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('SET Array[') do (
    IF NOT exist \\%%s\C$ (
        ECHO Server %%s is not reachable
    ) else (
        echo xcopy [source] [destination]
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: Appreciate the clarification; copied in your format & worked fine.  Must have had a syntax error somewhere (knew I wasn't crazy).